# Does a comprehensive security contract exist for individual app permissions?

Tags: google-drive-api

For example: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder describes the functional "perspective" of  SCOPE_APPFOLDER. I couldn't find any hint on whether SCOPE_APPFOLDER alone prevents the authorized application from accessing anything other on Google Drive than the App Folder's content, though. (The description kind of implies that this permission covers nothing else on Google Drive, but in matters of security, I am not comfortable relying on my intuition alone.)

Comment: What do you mean by "comprehensive security contract"? App Folders are usually used for storing app-related files such as config files and others that usually doesn't need need to be tampered with. The application can still access other folders aside from the app folder. its just that the App Folder is a special folder that's usually hidden.

Comment: @adjuremods "comprehensive security contract" might not be the best term here... What I mean is that whenever I ran into a Google Drive permission, I can't find a specification which would clearly state what that permission allows and what it doesn't allow. Do I understand you correctly that SCOPE_APPFOLDER provides access to folders other than the app folder?

Comment: From what I know, SCOPE_APPFOLDER will give you `drive.appfolder` access. If you want to have access to other files/folders, you can use SCOPE_FILE. You can look at the [Drive](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/Drive) class for more information.